# Why does opening the PDF in new tab have different behaviour

Tags: html, pdf, asp.net-core

I feel this has some simple answer but I can't find it on google.

In my ASP.net core application I have link which should open the pdf in new tab:

```
<a id="header-pp" href="@($"/files/PP.pdf")" target="_blank">@Localizer["Personal Data Protection"]</a>
```

When I open it in Chrome with right click on "Open link in new tab" everything works as expected, it opens the pdf. But if I click directly on the link, it's opening in new empty tab and response contains only some GUID.

Why is that?

Comment: What is your project verion and Chrome version? What is the generated html? I fail to reproduce with asp.net core 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

This is a browser setting. You can adjust the behavior. Here are the directions for chrome. I'm sure Firefox has something similar.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en